# Using SpannerClient how to get key after insert with mutation

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Precondition:

- have a table with PK a bit reverted sequence
- have a microservice serving thousand of read/write requests per second
- use DatabaseClient to access database with Kotlin/java

Use case:

- client ask to store an entity and then want to access it.

As far as I understood add the entity has to be done using Mutation object as parameter of the write method. The PK of the entity is calculated by spanner engine using the sequence (the column is defined like the official examples, defaulting to the sequence). As told, client has to be able to ask for the entity, so it has to know about the PK. But with mutations there is no way to get added/updated data (something that can be done with DML THEN RETURN). I'm wondering there is a way or good practice to solve this flow, in particular when there is no other unique info.
Only thing I have in mind is to use the PK to balance the data and a logical PK calculated by the engine to expose to the client but that is suboptimal cause I need to manage in sync the "id space" between multiple microservice instances.
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance